# Not able to sort an array of int using swapping method in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to input the length of array and then input the array elements. I was able to check the greatest value in case 1 but I make case 2 to re-sort the array from the smallest number to the biggest, but I wasn't able to do it.

Here's my code:

```
package peopleinfo;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class mainapp
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("please input the length of the array:");
    arraybuilder(sc1.nextInt());
  }

  public static void arraybuilder(int i)
  {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] array = new int[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++)
    {
      int o = j;
      System.out.println("please input the" + ++o + " number");
      array[j] = sc.nextInt();
    }
    for (int j2 = 0; j2 < array.length; j2++)
      System.out.print(array[j2] + "\t");
    System.out.println("what do you want to do ?\n 1 check the biggest number\n2 sort the array from the smallest\nterminate the app");
    int dwc = sc.nextInt();
    switch (dwc)
    {
      case 1:
        int k = 0;
        int max = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++)
        {
          if (array[j] > k)
          {
            max = j;
            k = array[j];
          }
        }
        System.out.println("the largest number is " + array[max]);
        break;

      case 2:
        int temp;
        boolean fixed = false;
        while (fixed = false)
        {
          fixed = true;
          for (int u = 0; u < array.length - 1; u++)
          {
            if (array[u] > array[u + 1])
            {
              temp = array[u + 1];
              array[u + 1] = array[u];
              array[u] = temp;
              fixed = false;
            }
          }
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++)
        {
          System.out.print(array[j] + "\t");
        }
        break;
      default:
        System.out.println("Error, please rerun the code:)");
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

I did not understand what am doing wrong?

Comment: **P.N:** should be `while(!fixed){` rather than `while(fixed=false){` .

Comment: Making the change in the above comment will _not_ fix the problem as the sorting algorithm being used is incorrect.  The `while` loop serves no purpose and should be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`while (fixed = false)` fixed=false is an assignment, and it will result as a "false" because fixed is assigned as false, which makes the while loop never start.

Answer (score 1):

```
 case 2:
                int temp;
                boolean fixed = false;
               while (fixed == false) {    // See the change here
                    fixed = true;
                    for (int u = 0; u < array.length - 1; u++) {
                        if (array[u] > array[u + 1]) {
                            temp = array[u + 1];
                            array[u + 1] = array[u];
                            array[u] = temp;
                            fixed = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
                    System.out.print(array[j] + "\t");
                }

                break;
```

In your case 2 the `while()` loop has `fixed = false`

Is should be `fixed == false` i.e. `while(fixed==false)`.

For more info follow the link... [Using the assignment operator instead of the equality operator](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2008/01/using_the_assig.html)

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the value false to fixed instead of comparing.Change the code as below and check it should work.

```
 case 2:
            int temp;
            boolean fixed = false;
            while (fixed == false) { //check this line
                fixed = true;
                for (int u = 0; u < array.length - 1; u++) {
                    if (array[u] > array[u + 1]) {
                        temp = array[u + 1];
                        array[u + 1] = array[u];
                        array[u] = temp;
                        fixed = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
                System.out.print(array[j] + "\t");
            }

            break;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have checked for a `boolean` as `while (fixed = false)`. Please note that you are assigning value there and to check `boolean` you need to use `==` like `while (fixed == false)` or `while (!fixed)`.

Because, when you use `while (fixed = false)` it doesn't return a `boolean` value, instead the `fixed` is assigned as `false`. You can see that the condition would always be false and the loop wouldn't execute.

Comment: Even with this change the sorting code won't produce the desired result.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Correcting the algorithm as `while (fixed == false)` works and produces the desired result in sorting the array in ascending order. I have tested it as well. Please let me know if you have any scenario it doesn't work for.

Comment: So you are basically saying that an array of size `N` can always be sorted in `O(N)` time?  This doesn't jive with what we know about sorting algorithms.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I think this question was not about a simple sorting algorithm. It's a single dimensional array in this problem and he tries a simple sorting. The reply was to solve this simple sorting which I think is resolved.  The question wasn't even about which algorithm should I be using or shortest path or efficiency, which would have attracted a best approach :) Please add your solution for the efficiency purpose. The usage of `fixed == false` in while loop haven't been checked by me. I just informed about the code correction **to make it work**.

Answer (score 0):

Your code for the second case is incorrect.  You appear to be trying to do a Bubble Sort, but you are missing a second loop.  I verified that your current code does *not* sort the array.  Try this code instead:

```
case 2:
    int temp;
    // Bubble sort the array
    for (int i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j=1; j < (array.length - i); j++) {
            if (array[j-1] > array[j]) {
                temp = array[j-1];
                array[j-1] = array[j];
                array[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int j=0; j < array.length; ++j) {
        System.out.print(array[j] + "\t");
    }
    break;
```

I also removed the `while` loop logic because it didn't seem to serve any purpose.

Comment: you to made the same mistake... as he had made... just change it... and his code works fine...